# How to setup AWS cluster to work with openCPU?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, opencpu, snow

I have two EC2 machines: master and slave. SSH keys are generated for user `ubuntu` and saved to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on both machines. Thus I can use the cluster from master node as `ubuntu` user like this:

```
library(doSNOW)

cluster_options <- 
c(rep(list(
        list(host = "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
             snowlib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")), 2))
cl <- makeCluster(cluster_options, type = "SOCK")
clusterApply(cl, 1:2, get("+"), 3)
stopCluster(cl)
```

But when I call it via `openCPU` it gives `permission denied` message.

Currently I'm thinking about two possible solutions:

1. Add SSH keys for `opencpu` user. But I don't have idea how to do it as `opencpu` is non-interactive user
2. Make slaves accessible by master without any SSH keys

I'd prefer the first way and definitely need help here. But second way is also ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I ended up with solution. It has several aspects:

1. Hostbased Authentication should be configured between two EC2 nodes. Good tutorial can be found here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Host-based_Authentication
2. `OpenCPU` should be installed on both nodes.
3. SSH keys should be generated for `www-data` user (`R` process is executed with this user). Delicate aspect here is that `www-data` is non-interactive user, so we need to make it interactive (edit `/etc/passwd`), generate SSH keypair for `www-data`, add public key to server node and make `www-data` non-interactive again.

Not so elegant, but it works :)